# Como generar un evento propio en un control de usuario

Tags: c#

Que tal buen dia a todos, diculpen tengo la siguiente duda, es sobre como hacer un evento custom en c# algo similiar a VB si es posible o no se puede en C#

Visual Basic

```
<System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("_Click")>
Public Class Boton

Public Event _Click(ByVal bandera As Boolean)

End Class
```

Comment: A lo que encontré si se puede Aquí tienes una referencia de Microsoft para que veas como crear tu propio evento personalizado > https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event

Comment: En que "lugar" quieres el evento? en una Clase o en algun control de usuario? Si nos comentas con un ejemplo de donde lo deseas utilizar la respuesta puede estar mejor enfocada

Comment: El evento va en un control de usuario, sera disparado por el evento click de un boton personalizado que cree

Comment: Winform o webform el control? Puedes colocar parte del código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar delegados y eventos

```
public delegate void RecibidoEventHandler(byte[] body);
public event RecibidoEventHandler Recibido;
```

Entonces en tu codigo para ejecutar solo "disparas" el evento

```
Recibido(....)
```

Para el observador/consumidor del evento

```
objetoA.Recibido+= MiClaseDelObjeto_Recibido;
```

que lo que hace es "apuntar" al metodo con la misma firma

```
private async void MiClaseDelObjeto_Recibido(byte[] body){
  //acciones...
}
```

Enlace que te puede ayudar

- [Utilizar delegados (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates)
- [Controlar y provocar eventos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/events/)